# Do any interesting POP-2 programs survive?

Tags: programming, history, mainframe

On a disk image (which I had for many years) from a [BESM-6](http://www.computer-museum.ru/english/besm6.htm), I've suddenly found a working [POP-2 (POPLAN)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POP-2#History) interpreter (for all these years I'd considered that area as useless bits and pieces of various files and binaries, because I've never heard of POP-2 implemented on the BESM-6).

There is only one complete working POP-2 program of any interest on that disk image: a [3D tic-tac-toe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_tic-tac-toe) game.

Does anyone has a recollection of using that language, and a stash of relatively small entertaining programs I could try on the interpreter?

I'm specifically interested in ["Man or Boy Test"](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Man_or_boy_test#Pop11) in POP-2. The Pop11 version provided doesn't compile.

Comment: That looks like an interesting functional language. Are the emulator and POP-2 image public? One could try to do some of the usual challenges (Project Euler etc.) in this language.

Comment: If you're interested in just the language features, you may have a better chance looking at a newer version of the language not requiring an emulator, like POP-11 or Poplog. I've found some POP-11 programs on RosettaCode, but I'm trying to find something non-trivial written specifically in POP-2.

Comment: @dirkt A toy environment is in http://www.mailcom.com/besm6/poplan.zip Beware of Russian error messages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://www.cs.otago.ac.nz/staffpriv/ok/pop2.htm
is mine.  I have in fact typed a lot of that code in,
have begun retyping RMYCIN, and have written but not
yet debugged other stuff.
I am not yet ready to put that stuff on line, but
would be happy to send it by e-mail to the original
poster.

As the Silver Book says, "FOURS is a game of three-dimensional noughts
and crosses, played on a 4x4x4 board."

My "stash" includes over 400 solutions to RosettaCode problems,
which I have not yet tested (because my compiler is not yet finished).
I would be thrilled to the very socks to be given a copy of the
POPLAN interpreter materials in exchange.

A word of warning:  the primary reference for Pop-2 is the Silver Book,
but the language kept on developing until the mid to late 1980s.  For
example, the Pop-2 system I used at Edinburgh included "properties"
(hash tables), which are not in the Silver Book.  By the time anyone
thought about revising that, Pop-11 had replaced Pop-2.  As an
example of Pop-2 development, the *language* described in the Silver
Book includes loopif Cond then Stmts close, which is a cross between
a 'while' loop and a Dijkstra 'do' loop (in that it can have more than
one alternative), but the *library* hadn't been updated to use that
feature.

The AI department at Edinburgh used an Emacs-like editor called
DOPE (the Display-Oriented Pop Editor) in the 1980s, a lineal
descendant of the "77 editor", using the "piece table" approach.
I might have that on a tape somewhere, but have no tape drive to
read it, sorry.

DAI Edinburgh lost a lot of stuff in a fire, sadly, including Pop-2
materials.

Oh yes, this should be Man or Boy.  UNTESTED!

```
"""

function A k x1 x2 x3 x4 x5;   
   function B kref;   
      vars k;   
      kref.cont -> k;   
      k-1 -> k;   
      k -> kref.cont;   
      A(k, B, x1, x2, x3, x4)   
   end;   
   if k <= 0 then   
      x4() + x5()   
   else   
      apply(B(% consref(k) %))   
   close      
end;   
A(10, lambda; 1 end,  lambda; -1 end,   
      lambda; -1 end, lambda; 1 end,   
      lambda; 0 end) =>   
"""
```

The Algol 60 function A has an integer parameter k passed by
value and five other parameters passed by name.  Pass by name was *meant*
to be like pass by reference, but what Algol 60 actually specified was
basically a pair of procedures (L,R), the L procedure being called when
you wanted an address to store into and the R procedure being called
when you wanted a value (the modern word for R is "thunk").  That's
why the Algol code has x4 + x5 and the Pop-2 code has x4() + x5(),
and it's always why the Pop-2 code has anonymous functions
(lambda ;  end) in the top level call to A where Algol
had constants.

The thing that makes this example a bit of a pain in Pop-2, and *more*
of a pain than in Pop-11, is the scope rules.  A funny thing happened
in the early days of Lisp.  McCarthy et all *meant* to specify the
same kind of static scope rules that Lisp and Scheme now enjoy, but
by mistake implemented 'dynamic scope'. One way to think of it is
that all references to an identifier always go to the same static
location; when you enter a scope where a variable is (re)declared
its old value is saved on a stack, and restored when you leave that
scope.  (Common Lisp now calls this "fluid binding".)  Pop-2 went
with Lisp.  By the mid-1980s 'vars' had been replaced by 'lvars'
("Lexically scoped VARiableS").  The language described in the
Silver Book didn't have lvars.  Nor did functions capture their
non-local variables in "closures".  Closures had to be made by hand.
B(% ... %) says "make a closure where the code part is B and the
values of ... will be passed as extra arguments at the end."  Now
B needs to *change* k, so we stuff the value of k into a one-word
record called a "reference".

Finally, => is called the "print arrow".  Inside a function, it
prints and removes the top item on the stack.  At top level, it
prints and removes everything on the stack.

Comment: Welcome to Retrocomputing Stack Exchange. I was planning to send you an email, but as you're on the site it's easiest for me to tell you now: the bottom link is broken (it should point to the file in /pop.d/, which exists) and page 261 from `/pop2.d/silver-6-library.pdf` is missing. Thanks for answering on the site, and I hope you stay to share more knowledge. You can [subscribe to this question's feed](//retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/feeds/question/1954) if you want to be notified when more POP-2 resources turn up.

Comment: @raok Thank you! Two things: for some reason the version I have requires spelling the less-than-or-equal operator as =< and there is an execution error "СОNТ(Х)/DЕSТRЕF(Х) Х NOT A REFERENCE". Oh, and I had to use the syntax ".x4 + .x5" instead of the empty parentheses.

Comment: Oops, my error.  The only way to spell less-than-or-equal-to is =<, a spelling that survives in Prolog and Erlang to this day.  Yes, I know that there's a page missing from the PDF, but I don't have the book any more.  It's part of the documentation of the "QuIzzing Machine" library, and we can manage without it.  I have fixed the broken link.

Comment: It is true that .f is a legal way to call a function, but so is f().  The Blue Book made this clear in section 5.1 Expressions of the reference manual, back in 1968.  The "FOURS.POP" program   If you look at the Silver Book (silver-4-library.pdf, page 144) you will see ITEMREAD() being called like that.

Comment: As for the run time error, the only argument B has is a consref(k), which had *better* be a ref.  It sounds as though you have a more-or-less working Poplan system to try things on.  Can I have it?   Like I said, my compiler is not finished yet.

Comment: Ah.  Sorry, I juggled the code around several times.  I think replacing the nested call to A with       A(k, B(% kref %), x1, x2, x3, x4)
  should do the trick.

Comment: @raok The POP-2 implementation I have is POPLAN on BESM-6. It accepts more or less the standard language but all diagnostics are in Russian. With B(% kref %), and 10 as the first argument of A, I get a stack overflow, and with 4, I get (translated) "ARG.НD,ТL,NULL NOT A LIST". Regarding the calling convention,  `:function a x y; x() + y() => end;
:a(lambda; 3 end, lambda; 5 end);

** 8`
works, but not in the man-or-boy case.

Comment: @Leo B. ARG HD, TL, NULL NOT A LIST means that x.hd, x.tl, or x.null was evaluated and x was not a list.  There are no references to hd, tl, or null in this code.  Errors in Pop-2 are supposed to be signalled by calling errfun(culprit, integer).  I would expect this to report the culprit.  If not, vars olderrfun; errfun -> olderrfun; function errfun x n; x => olderrfun -> errfun; olderrfun(x, n) end; should let you intercept the call and find out what the culprit is.  I would very much like to add your POPLAN system to my web site anyway.  Please?

Comment: @raok Printing the error (with the func. decl. under the name myerrfun and assigning to errfun) makes things worse; I think there is a stack overflow and there is no check. A(4, ...) should call B exactly 7 times with k = 4,3,2,1,3,2,1; instead, I'm getting 4,3,2,1,3,2,1,0,2,1,0,-1,1,0,... and adding a debug print of recursion depth shows a runaway recursion. I'm preparing a minimal confuguration of the BESM-6 user space emulator to run the POPLAN system. I'll make it available soon.

Comment: @raok Please see http://www.mailcom.com/besm6/poplan.zip

Comment: @raok Any luck? Please write to me: leob at the domain of the file.

Comment: Unfortunately, the compiler I have is a "boy" compiler. The following very simple program demonstrates that closures passed back into the original context don't work correctly: FUNCTION A K X;
FUNCTION B; K-1->K; K=> IF K > 0 THEN A(-1, B) CLOSE; END;
IF K > 0 THEN .B ELSE .X CLOSE END;
A(10, 0);

It should print 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 but prints 9 -2

Comment: Ah, the Silver Book. That was the second programming-language book I read (after *The Complete Cybernaut* which taught me FORTRAN). This was in high school, and we didn’t have access to computers back then, in the Old Country. After FORTRAN, discovering what POP-2 could do completely blew my mind.

Answer (score 2):

Looking through Usenet, I came across a post on `comp.lang.pop` (posted 2016/10/27 02:36) asking for information about POP-2:

> I am trying to collection materials relating to Pop-2 (Poplog's predecessor).
>   http://www.cs.otago.ac.nz/staffpriv/ok/pop2.htm
>   lists what I currently have. [...]

The information that this person has collected so far includes 'a selection of programs from the POP-2 library of the Edinburgh 4100 installation'<sup>1</sup>, spanning three-and-a-bit .PDF files ([file 4](http://www.cs.otago.ac.nz/staffpriv/ok/pop2.d/silver-4-library.pdf), [file 5](http://www.cs.otago.ac.nz/staffpriv/ok/pop2.d/silver-5-library.pdf), [file 6](http://www.cs.otago.ac.nz/staffpriv/ok/pop2.d/silver-6-library.pdf), [file 7](http://www.cs.otago.ac.nz/staffpriv/ok/pop2.d/silver-7-end.pdf)). These scans do not contain text but are legible enough to be typed out by hand.

### Index of Edinburgh 4100 POP-2 library

In this index, page numbers are given as per the file, not the scanned book. The first number is the start of the description and the second number is the start of the code.

#### [File 4](http://www.cs.otago.ac.nz/staffpriv/ok/pop2.d/silver-4-library.pdf)

- LIB ALLSORT - p2, p4
- LIB ASSOC - p5, p9
- LIB CALL AND EXPLAIN - p11, p15
- LIB DCOMPILE - p16, p18
- LIB DEBUG - p19, p22
- LIB EASYFILE - p23, p34
- LIB EQUATIONS - p38, p40
- LIB FOR - p42, p44
- LIB FOURS - p46, p47
  Note: This may be the "3D tic-tac-toe" game that you mentioned.

#### [File 5](http://www.cs.otago.ac.nz/staffpriv/ok/pop2.d/silver-5-library.pdf)

- LIB FULL MEMOFNS - p1, p7
- LIB GRAPH TRAVERSER - p10, p16
- LIB INDEX - p18, p20
- LIB INVTRIG - p22, p23
- LIB KALAH - p24, p25
- LIB MATRIX - p30, p32
- LIB MEMOFNS - p35, p39
  Note: A less-full(?) version of LIB FULL MEMOFNS (earlier version?)
- LIB NEW STRUCTURES - p41, p46

#### [File 6](http://www.cs.otago.ac.nz/staffpriv/ok/pop2.d/silver-6-library.pdf)

- LIB PLOT - p1, p4
- LIB POPEDIT - p7, p12
- LIB POPSTATS - p14, p15
- LIB PROOF CHECKER - p28, p35
- ??? QUIZZING MACHINE - p40.5?, p43?
  Note: A page of the scan is missing. It is the description, so the program remains complete.

#### [File 7](http://www.cs.otago.ac.nz/staffpriv/ok/pop2.d/silver-7-end.pdf)

- LIB RANDOM - p1, p2
- LIB RANDPACK - p3, p4
- LIB SETS - p5, p7

---

<sup>1</sup> from *Programming in Pop-2*, by Burstall, Collins, and Popplestone.

Comment: The aforementioned `pop2.html` page mentioned RMYCIN, a program which I am currently investigating. I hope to have a copy soon (although it may be too big to include directly in this answer).

Comment: Indeed, the FOURS program looks like the original of what I have. There are a few insignificant modifications, e.g. NOT(A=B) is written as A /= B, the RANDOM function is provided verbatim rather than read from a file, etc.